# Build apk in android studio

Tags: android

Pls help,this is my first app and i have been having serious issues in installing the app  on my phone:

After building the apk of my app it takes forever to install on my phone.

I have searched for solutions but none worked for me. My device is huwaie P6 running Jellybean v4,2.

this is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.micheal.stephen.geo"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

pls what might be the problem?

Comment: try a different phone? nothing seems out of the ordinary

Comment: Can we see some adb logcat output from when you're installing?

Comment: how do you install the apk on your phone, do you run the apk from your phone or run directly to it?

Comment: Try `adb install /path/to/apk` in command line?

Comment: @klutch I ran the app on my phone because when I tried running the app directly to it, it gave me the same issue

Comment: @user866762 I ran the app on my phone

Comment: Follow [this guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html) to setup debugging on the phone and capture some logcat? Also, how big is the compiled APK?

Comment: please show us the logcat output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, i actually did a phone restart and it worked fine.